# JQuery JSON Array formatting/serializing before posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{ 
 "firstArrayOfJSON": [
          {
            "something" : "something"
          },
          {
            "another" : "another"
          },
          {
            "secondArrayOfJson" : [
                              {
                                "something" : "something",
                                "other" : "other"
                               }
                             ]
          }
         ]
      }
```

On variable watch (Google Chrome), before any processing, the object appears as:

```
[0]: Object
     something : "something"
     another : "another"
     secondArrayOfJson : Object
                         [0]: something : "something",
                         [1]: other : "other"
```

And the following JQuery ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                success: success,
                dataType: "json"
            });
```

On the server (Express JS), I have a test service that just spits out the request body. I then proceed to check the response on the client.

The response has changed:

The first level array show as:

```
[0]: Object
     something : "something"
     another : "another"
     secondArrayOfJson : Object
                         [0][something] : "something",
                         [1][other] : "other"
```

I can still use the object normally: `firstArrayOfJson[2].secondArrayofJson[0].something`

I have tested storing on a Mongo server and the array elements look really as `[0][something]` (Robomongo)

When I add another object to the `secondArrayOfJson`, the "problem" disappears.

So unless this is a viewer issue happening both on Google Chrome and Robomongo, this is really how the object is passed.

I wonder if there is a logical reason for this or if I should worry about anything I am doing.

Comment: Probably has something to do with how jQuery serializes the data you are sending to the server and how your server processes it. E.g. `{foo: [1, 2]}` becomes something like `foo[0]=1&foo[1]=2`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my AJAX query was missing two important paramenters. According to JQ documentation:

> data Type: PlainObject or String or Array Data to be sent to the
>   server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.
>   It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to
>   prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If
>   value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
>   based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

By adding

```
processData : false,
contentType : "application/json"
```

I make sure JQ keeps the object intact for the request. I've tried and it worked just fine.

Thanks to [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) shedding a light.